# ¿Como crear diferentes hojas en un mismo Excel guardado con anterioridad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un `.xlsx` guardado de la siguiente manera..

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
writer = ExcelWriter('C:/prueba.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'INTRO')
writer.save()
```

una vez que lo guardo, a mitad del `script` necesito leer ese `.xlsx` y lo hago de la siguiente manera...

```
df_read = pd.read_excel('C:/prueba.xlsx')
```

Ahora mi pregunta es la siguiente.. ¿Cómo hago para agregar una hoja en el `.xlsx` ?.

por ejemplo :

> hoja1=INTRO y hoja2=DF_READ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que pretendes almacenar otro DataFrame o parte de él en otra hoja del mismo xlsx. Para ello solo debes reutilizar tu objeto `writer`.

```
df1.to_excel(writer, 'INTRO')
df2.to_excel(writer, 'DF_READ')
writer.save()
```

Aunque dado que ningún método o atributo de la clase es considerado como público según la documentación, lo correcto es usar `with`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter


df1 = pd.DataFrame({"AAA": (1, 2, 3),
                    "BBB": (5, 7, 11)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"CCC": (13,17, 19),
                    "DDD": (23,29, 31)})

with ExcelWriter('C:/prueba.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, 'INTRO')
    df2.to_excel(writer, 'DF_READ')
```

Si quieres agregar una hoja a un archivo ya cerrado o que tienes en disco, usa el **modo `"a"` (`append`)** cuando abras el archivo con `ExcelWriter`. No obstante, **xlsxwriter no admite dicho modo, debe usar openpyxl** en este caso:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter


df3 = pd.DataFrame({"EEE": (37, 41, 43),
                    "FFF": (47, 53, 59)})

with ExcelWriter('c/:prueba.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
    df3.to_excel(writer, 'DF_SHEET3')
```

Para hacerlo con xlsxwriter necesitarías cargar previamente todas las hojas en DataFrames y crear un nuevo xlsx.